# Transformar serie temporal em base 100 no R

Tags: r

Existe alguma função que converta toda uma série temporal em base 100 no R? Não existindo, qual seria a solução para o problema?
Obrigado

Comment: Pode clarificar a pergunta com um exemplo de dados e de saída esperada?

Comment: Tenho uma série temporal e gostaria de dividir todos os valores pelo primeiro e multiplicar por 100. Sendo assim o primeiro elemento seria 100 pois ele é dividido por ele mesmo e multiplicado por 100, o segundo valor também serie dividido pelo primeiro e multiplicado por 100, o terceiro também seria dividido pelo primeiro e multiplicado por 100 e assim sucessivamente. Não sei se fui claro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há uma função R para fazer isso, é portanto necessário definir uma.

```
base100 <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE){
  if(na.rm) x <- na.omit(x)
  100*x/x[1]
}

set.seed(1234)
y <- as.ts(cumsum(rnorm(20)))

base100(y)
```

Note que se `x[1]` for igual a zero, a função dá erro. Deixei assim mesmo para o usuário ter a opção de corrigir isso caso a caso, como achar melhor.